# Auto scroll textview

Tags: android, scroll, textview

I have this layout, but am not able to set the ready_text textview to autoscroll vertically to bottom when this textview has more than 2 lines of text. Can anybody help me solve this problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topHolder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ready_text"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/recognized_text_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:textColor="@color/black" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsHolder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnUndo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:text="@string/btnUndo"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSym"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:text="@string/btnSym"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnReturn"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:src="@drawable/enter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAt"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:text="@string/btnAt"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnExclamation"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:text="@string/btnExclamation"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnQuestion"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:text="@string/btnQuestion"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnComma"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:text="@string/btnComma"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDot"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:text="@string/btnDot"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSpace"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:text="@string/btnSpace"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/writingSurface"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttonsHolder"
        android:layout_below="@id/topHolder" >

        <com.myapp.myview
            android:id="@+id/my_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/yellow" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

also im trying to scroll using this code:

```
final int scrollAmount = ready_text.getLayout()
                    .getLineTop(ready_text.getLineCount())-ready_text.getHeight();
            Log.v("DARE", scrollAmount+"");
            // if there is no need to scroll, scrollAmount will be <=0
            if(scrollAmount>0)
                ready_text.scrollTo(0, scrollAmount);
            else
                ready_text.scrollTo(0,0);
```

Comment: I think the `ready_text.getHeight()` is tripping this up. You have the lineCount which is a "small" number (i.e. 1 or 2 or 3 lines), and the height, which is a "large" number (i.e. 20 pixels).